# Gibberish that should make sense

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle

***Note*** that this puzzle has evolved considerably since it was first posted. The edits were based on other puzzlers' inputs and I really appreciate the help.

---

> Everlasting pore in greenery and everlasting pain, or
>   Away!—the two most elite in the werewolf pack worded
>   And a hairdo, a party, or just to perform
>   Lastly, many a man.
>
> Those two are but only
>   its more gentlemanly cousins.
>
> Many of you know more
>   its more fonder form, as do most children.
>   But you call it a tomb!
>   Why? It's very much living.
>
> Something taken for granted,
>   something you wouldn't live without.

"Fonder"? Go to $\rightarrow$

> overactive writing, shift, set of rules-
>   what spiders make is worldwide-
>   the lingua franca-
>   pile, swap-
>   Commercial, between nets, sites in three letters-
>   Queries/doubts-
>   302626

**To solve you take the root —

halve the doubled middle and shred its companion,

that duo describing oneself's possessiveness.**

Comment: Are you sure the [cryptic-crosswords] tag is appropriate here? I don't see any crossword grids, and there are very specific rules for cryptic clues.

Comment: Sorry. It was supposed to be [crossword-clues]. Mistook one for the other.

Comment: I don't see any crossword clues here either.

Comment: Neither of those work as [tag:crossword-clues].

Comment: Neither of those are crossword clues. Please read tag wikis before using the tags if you're unsure of exactly what they mean.

Comment: *Not* crossword-clues.  Tag removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After conversation with OP in The Sphinx's Lair, we've learned that the intended answer is

> **TUM**

The riddle was reworked subsequently to more clearly point at the intended answer.
This updated post addresses the new riddle.

```
Everlasting pore in greenery and everlasting pain, or
```

> "Everlasting" should be interpreted as "Endless", and then this line solved as wordplay.
>  Pore in greenery (STOMA) and pain (ACHE), made endless and merged, give  **STOMACH**.
>
>  The next three lines spell out the word **ABDOMEN** as follows --

```
Away!—the two most elite in the werewolf pack worded
```

> **AB**.  "Ab-" is a prefix meaning "away"; Alpha/Beta are the top of pack wolf hierarchy

```
And a hairdo, a party, or just to perform
```

> **DO**

```
Lastly, many a man.
```

> **MEN**

```
Those two are but only
its more gentlemanly cousins.
```

> Now that we're thinking about STOMACH and ABDOMEN, these lines tell us that these two words are more formal (gentlemanly) words for the answer to the riddle.

```
Many of you know more
its more fonder form, as do most children.
But you call it a tomb!
Why? It's very much living.
```

> "fonder" here evokes using a term of endearment (of sorts) for one's stomach/abdomen. We kind of got that from the previous two lines, but this confirms it. We might informally call our stomach a **TUMMY**, as might many children.  Or, apparently exclusively to British English, the word **TUM** might be used.  Either of these words sound a little like "tomb".  So this stanza is supposed to get us from Stomach and Abdomen to TUMMY  and/or TUM.

```
Something taken for granted,
something you wouldn't live without.
```

> This is just fluff.  Yes, we take our tummies for granted, and if we didn't have one we'd be dead.

```
"Fonder"? Go to →

overactive writing, shift, set of rules-
what spiders make is worldwide-
the lingua franca-
pile, swap-
Commercial, between nets, sites in three letters-
Queries/doubts-
302626
```

> This gives more guidance on which "fonder" word to use.
>  The clues lead us to https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302626
>  because protocol, world-wide-web, english, stack/exchange, com, questions, and the number.
>
>  The page in question talks about suffixes like "-y" and "-ie" used to form more familiar, endearing versions of words (i.e. *dog* to *doggy* or *doggie*). One of the words listed is "tummy" and, as the context of this page's mention in the riddle is telling us to consider "Fonder" words, this suggests the answer we want is "TUMMY".
>
>  However, talking to OP in TSL, the intention was:
>  • See "tummy" on the page to confirm we're on the right track with TUMMY
>  • Realize, somehow, that the word we want is the not-endearing version of our word
>    (even though the context and content of the indicated page seems to suggest the opposite!)
>  • Get "TUM" from "TUMMY" as TUMMY is supposedly a more familiar, endearing version of "TUM"
>    (apparently relying on the provided page as the basis for that assertion; unfortunately,
>     *it's not true* - both *tummy* and *tum* derive directly from *stomach*, not one from the other —
>     and in (say) US English where "tummy" is ubiquitous, "tum" is practically unheard of!)

```
To solve you take the root —  
halve the doubled middle and shred its companion,  
that duo describing oneself's possessiveness.
```

> So, to patch around the "tummy"/"tum" issue, this last bit was added.
>  It tells us our final answer is found by taking the "root" of TUMMY,
>  and goes on to explain -
>   • "halve the doubled middle", or cut out one ***M***
>   • "shred its companion", or destroy the last ***Y***
>   • "that duo" (***M, Y***) "describing oneself's possessiveness" (***my***) as confirmation of what to cut
>
>  leaving us, at last, with the intended answer:  **TUM**.

---

I'm left with one concern about the riddle as it now stands (but do not recommend OP keep tweaking the puzzle - at some point, it's time to just learn from past mistakes and move forward) -

> The whole "follow these clues to this webpage" section is probably extraneous now:  you can get TUMMY quite easily without it, nothing here actually suggests you are supposed to *de*-familiarize the word you have, the relationship between TUM and TUMMY suggested by that page is specious, and the final addition sufficiently clues getting from TUMMY to TUM without it.

That quibble aside, the riddle in its final form is much better than it started, and now takes a reasonable path through its clues to a well-indicated solution.  Huzzah!

Comment: See the hint. You're close.

Comment: It's not AB for stomach. The prefix ab- means "away". Abstain, for example.

Comment: It's not an hint. The first time I labeled it a hint, but I'd edited it to make it a part of the puzzle which you probably didn't notice. See the puzzle now.

Comment: Would you mind if edited the question now? I honestly don't like how I set it up. I know it would not be fair. But I'm itching to improve the puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting two answers, perhaps someone can combine them in a meaningful way.

1:

> Abdomen

*A person's stomach.*

> Yep

*Away!—the two most elite in the werewolf pack worded*

> Not sure about Away!, but Alpha-wolf/Beta-wolf -> "AB-"

*And a hairdo, a party, or just to perform*

> "-do-"

*Lastly, many a man.*

> "-men"

2.

> Dirt

*Many of you know it's fondled form
as do most children.*

> Many kids play in the dirt

*But you call it a tomb!*

> Dead are buried under here

*Why? It's very much living.*

> Bacteria in the soil

*Something taken for granted,
something you wouldn't live without.*

> This would apply to both answers, as well as what is common to both

Possible overall answer?

> Bacteria? - present in both the abdomen and soil?

Wiser folks than me may be able to tie this in better.

Comment: See the hint, you're close.

Comment: Puzzle has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Abdomen ?

A person's stomach, or

> Abdomen is another word for stomach

Away!—the two most elite in the werewolf pack worded
And a hairdo, a party, or just to perform

> To be provided ...

Lastly, many a man.

> Last three letters represent many a man (that is MEN) !

Many of you know it's fondled form
as do most children.

> Pregnant ladies have big tummies under which childrens are made/shaped affectionately !

But you call it a tomb!

> Perhaps not a tomb, if the neonate is alive ! (bit harsh on my part !!)

Why? It's very much living.

> Yes, an abdomen lives very much with always one or other gastric activities or in the pregnancy contrext, it is alive very much with the expected child / children !!

Something taken for granted,

> Tummy (also known by this) is taken for granted ...for making fun

something you wouldn't live without.

> We cannot survive without our abdomen!

Comment: Think more on `tummy`.

Comment: @Soha Farhin Pine I guesss the word being sought is not 'Abortion' based on the title of this riddle !

Comment: See the hint, you're close.

Comment: Puzzle has been edited.